# Christmas light transformer (500 LEDs, 31 V, 0.06 W)

Tags: led, transformer

I have a set of 500 LED Christmas lights for which I want to replace the power supply. The tag on the lights reads:

- Lamp: 3 V - 0.06 W
- Transformer: 31 V - 3.6 VA
- Set rating: 31 V -3.6 W

Is there a standard LED driver I can use, and if so what do I need to look for?

Comment: A 3.6 watt (or 3.6 VA) transformer can only supply 60 LEDs if each LED is rated at 0.06 watts. So, something is wrong somewhere and this cannot be answered.

Comment: A resistor or electronic circuit must be somewhere (in the transformer?) to limit the current.

Answer (score 1):

The set rating of 3.6W cannot be right. You need about 30W of power (assuming per lamp 3v - 0.06w you posted is correct).

As for the voltage of 31V, it really depends on how the LEDs are wired together and I have to assume that it's correct.

Since 31V is an odd voltage rating for power supply, you will need a 36V power supply (or a more common 48V). The power of 30W should be supported by almost any of these, but do check the ratings.

However, what I would recommend is that you get an LED dimmer along with this. Since you are supplying more voltage and power than your LED strip can handle, it's best to start out with the lowest dimmer setting and never hit the full setting. Alternatively I would recommend putting a resistor in series, but you need to calculate current passing through the LED strip etc for this.